# how to update data from internal storage?

Tags: android, android-launcher

I created an application to *protect children* and *allow parents to control the access* to the *application*.

It is a launcher with *two profiles*: `Parent` and `child`.

- `Parents` have *administrative rights* and *can select applications* from a `list view`.
- After the selection of applications, that `list` shall be *saved* in a file *stored internally*.
- After that App *should normally* return to `MainActivity`. But during returning to `MainActivity`, the update does not happen!!
- After debugging, I noticed that the above process *failed* and also confirmed the issue by the method of reading `application files`.

> I do not know what to do! Do I restart my `Activity` or I use `sharedPreferences` for *recording* applications.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a method for updating. And use that method inside [onActivityResult - Method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29).

E.g.:

```
 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    reload();
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);       
 }
```

`private void reload(){
//update your stuff 
}`

Comment: CAn you give me an example of using such method. And what to put result codes requestcode

Comment: [There you go :)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities). You can define your own request and resultcodes. Also take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10407192/2245646)